# SQL selecting or & and

Tags: sql, select

I have this following data stored in sql database: [image]

I want to write a sql statement to return the numbers of occurrence for each SessionID all at once. For instance, it should return [2,1,3] for sessionID 1,2,3

I tried this: but seems like it is wrong cuz it returns 6.

```
    select count(`SessionID`) from table  order by `SessionID`;
```

thx!

Comment: Look into `GROUP BY`

Comment: thx!  i am new to sql as i messed up order by with group by. I thought all sessionIDs will be "ordered".

Comment: select COUNT(SessionId)  as TotalSession,SessionIdf rom TabbleName group by SessionId

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Select 
SessionId , 
count(`SessionID`) 
from 
table 
group by SessionId 
order by SessionId
```

It will retrieve two column where first column is the sessionid ( 1,2,3 ) and second column will be the number of occurrence of each sessionid. Another thing , you can ignore the **order by** clause here. Implying it will just make the **sessionid** ordered.Hope it will help.